# MS Word 2010 hyperlink issues

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I'm revising a MS Word procedural document not of my creation using Word 2010. As I attempt to create hyperlinks from the Table of Contents to newly added document content, the hyperlink window that opens doesn't show the new document content. Clearly, this makes hyperlink creation impossible. I've not seen this condition before, have never seen this problem described anywhere and have no idea how to correct it. Page breaks have been properly employed and I've gotten no incompatibility warnings. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you attach a Screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a lot of detail to your question about how the original TOC was created, so I am going to give you a basic answer.

In Word, the Table of Contents (TOC) is typically created based off the font styles.

[image]

> The easiest way to create a table of contents is to use the built-in
>   heading styles. You can also create a table of contents that is based
>   on the custom styles that you have applied. Or you can assign the
>   table of contents levels to individual text entries.

If the newly added documents don't have the styles which the TOC is looking for, they will not be included in the TOC.

[Create a table of contents or update a table of contents](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-table-of-contents-or-update-a-table-of-contents-1bee8114-2c58-46fb-a884-64c6dfecaeca)